# df shows too much space on tmpfs

Tags: chroot, tmpfs, df

I have a server (SLES 11 running on a VMware hypervisor if that matters) with a tmpfs partition meant for mysql temporary tables, and I run mysql chrooted.

`df -h` gives me strange outpupt:

```
root@db12.lab:~# df -h /usr/chroot/tmp/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            77G   66G  7.9G  90% /usr/chroot/tmp
```

While `mount` goes like this:

```
root@db12.lab:~# mount | grep tmpfs
tmpfs on /usr/chroot/tmp type tmpfs (rw,size=512m)
```

The database runs allright and I don't see any fs-related errors in the log. I did try to stop the daemons and mount/unmount the FS, but it didn't help.

I wonder what it might mean and how such kind of problems is solved?

It doesn't affect anything, but it's somewhat mystical and I'd like it to go.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, remounting did actually help, I've just retried it just in case and all the magic is gone. Could the mods please close the question?

Comment: It is possible to answer your question as well, and this is maybe a better solution.

Comment: Well what actually happened is the tmpfs partition was not mounted, but it was listed in mount, so df -h was reporting the usage of / instead, since it's the 'parent' partition of a directory which was supposed to be the mountpoint for tmpfs. Mount, on the other hand, lied to me: 'It is possible that files /etc/mtab and /proc/mounts don't match. The first file is based only on the mount command options, but the content of the second file also depends on the kernel and others settings'. I should have checked /proc/mounts, too.

Comment: I'd say answer your own question and mark it, since you solved it yourself.

Comment: It would be allright if I had a real problem with this weird behavior. I should have double check things before asking, so let there be a comment for anyone who does something like this, but I think it's not actually an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using the mount command you'll see whatever options are in `/etc/mtab`. But `/etc/mtab` is just a file, there is nothing magical about it. It can get out of sync with reality in various ways. For example `/etc/mtab` cannot be updated if the file system it is located on is read-only. And if `/etc/mtab` is located on a file system, which is persistent across reboots, then it may contain entries from a previous boot.

The contents of `/proc/mounts` is however a view into the actual kernel data structures. As long as `/proc` is mounted, you will always get up to date information from `/proc/mounts`. But though the format of `/etc/mtab` and `/proc/mounts` are identical, there may be some information which is only available in `/etc/mtab`.